# How to pass props in StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, stack-navigator

```
const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Tabs
  },

  Collection_Products : {
    screen : Collection_Products,
    navigationOptions :  ({ navigation }) => ({

      title : `${navigation.state.params.name.toUpperCase()}`
    }),
  },

  MainProduct : {
    screen : (props) => <MainProduct {...props} />,
  },

});


export default class MainNav extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checkout: { lineItems: { edges: [] } }
    };

  }

 method1 = (args) => {

}
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <MainNavigator checkout= {this.state.checkout} method1 = {this.method1}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am using react native to build application. I want to pass method 1 to different child components. How can I pass method1 function in MainProduct Component? With the syntax I am using I am only able to pass navigator props to child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the props as below. You need to send props name as 'screenProps' literally then only it is send. Yeah, This is little strange. I tried to change the name of the props, it did not get trough.

```
const propsForAll = {
checkout:/*your checkout data */, 
method1: /**Your medhod1*/
}

<View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <MainNavigator screenProps={propsForAll}/>
      </View>
```

Comment: obsolete as of version 5.0. They switched to React Context.

Answer (score 4):

## The accepted answer is outdated for React Navigation v5 and v6

**screenProps** is no longer available, which caused several problems.

## Use react **context** instead

Quote from react-navigation 5.x,

*Due to the component based API of React Navigation 5.x, we have a much better alternative to screenProps which doesn't have these disadvantages: React Context. Using React Context, it's possible to pass data to any child component in a performant and type-safe way, and we don't need to learn a new API!*

## Alternatively, you may use routeProps

Passing parameters to routes. v6 [doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params)

`navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })`

## In case you are new to **context**

Here is how you may use context to pass props.

Example:

```
  import React from 'react'

  // Create context outside of your component
  // which can be export to your child component
  const MyContext = React.createContext()

  export default function MyParentComponent() {
    const myContext = {
      whatIWhatMyChildToKnow: 'Hi, I am your father.',
    }
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={myContext}>
         // Dont pass your own props to your navigator 
         // other than RNavigation props
        <YourStackNavigator>
          ...stack logic
        </YourStackNavigator>
      </MyContext.Provider>
    )
  }

  // access your context value here
  function MyChildScreen() {
    const { whatIWhatMyChildToKnow } = React.useContext(MyContext)
    // will display 'Hi, I am your father.'
    return <span>{whatIWantMyChildToKnow}</span>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want `screenProps`, from the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html):

```
const SomeStack = StackNavigator({
  // config
});

<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as 
  this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```